# Push notification integration using parse.com in phonegap for windows phone 8 app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, parse-platform, phonegap-plugins

Can anyone please tell me how to integrate Push notifications using parse.com in Phonegap for windows phone 8 app?
I browsed on net for solution but no luck. Currently Parse push plugins are available only for android and iOS(https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin). Please guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Furher moderator @josilber decided to delete my answer because I had posted it elsewhere, despite this question being asked multiple times. So if you still have issues with this, or if anyone else does please refer to my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34231058/873177).

Answer (score -1):

You can use these plugins as a starting point. The majority of code for the Parse integration will be native.

Your plugin will do just the basic stuff, like channel subscription.

Unfortunatelly there's no "plug and play" solution at this time.