# Parse SDK Windows 8.1 : Device not getting registered on Parse.com portal

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, windows-8.1

I followed the documentation(https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#push-notifications-setting-up-push) by Parse for sending Push to Windows 8.1 device. But, I am not able to get through the first step ie. "Installation". As per the documentation I followed , the channel should get registered instantly. I have enabled "Toast capable" within the Package.appxmanifest file in my Windows 8.1 Universal App(C#).

I have also authenticated the App by adding the Package Security Identifier and the Client Secret to the Parse.com Windows Push Credentials settings. But still no success. Can anyone tell me if I am missing anything or if Parse SDK is supported for Universal Windows 8.1 C# App.

Comment: How did you get the SID and the Client secret from the dev.windows.com site when registering your app? Thanks

Comment: @robcsi You only need to do that for authenticated push notifications. It is not required for unauthenticated pushes. I had Parse working for WP8 back in December, but sadly this year for some reason iOS, Android, and WP8 all stopped working. We got Android and iOS back but I am having significant issues with WP8 still. Incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had Parse working for WP8 [as per instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34231058/873177). So this is to say it is definitely doable, follow those steps there to see if you missed any steps.

**Caveat**

We are using Cordova, but I had to end up doing this part natively. It was working in December 2015 but mysteriously this year we had issues with Parse on *all* 3 device platforms (iOS, Android, WP8). I'm still spending time trying to figure out why WP8 just doesn't work now, can't even get the device to register to a channel anymore...